# SSRS Calculated field Skip NULL

Tags: reporting-services, time

I am trying to make some calculations in a SSRS report.
I have times in the column Hours: "08:25:21" and some of them are NULL.

WORKS:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), Nothing,Fields!Hours.Value)
```

I want to extract the hours from the time:
ERROR for blank:

```
=IIf(IsError(Hour(Fields!Hours.Value.toString())),Nothing,Hour(Fields!Hours.Value.toString()))
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value),Nothing,Hour(Fields!Hours.Value.toString()))
```

How can I do this so I will get a Nothing when no Hours.value is present?

Danny

Comment: Try `=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), Nothing, Hour(Fields!Hours.Value))`.

Comment: #Error for all values Warning 2 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Log_in_Sec1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from type 'TimeSpan' to type 'Date' is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **Hours** field is a **TimeSpan**, you can use the [TimeSpan.Hours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) property.

I've been able to make this work by [adding a function to the code of the report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx).

```
Function GetHours(timeSpan as TimeSpan) As String
    If timeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Return timeSpan.Hours
    End If
End Function
```

Now you can use this expression: `=Code.GetHours(Fields!Hours.Value)`.

Comment: This is correct but it still gives me an #Error if the field with the time is Empty. My examples above also work, but they give me an error where Hours is NULL.

Comment: [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Log_in_Sec.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Where are you getting your Timestamp field from? Is it a calculated field?

Comment: Directly from a SQL table, it's not a calculated field.

Comment: The scope of this was to calculate the total difference from 8hours a day. So I modified the Funtion to return a Integer and changed the return to: Return (timeSpan.Hours*3600+timeSpan.Minutes*60+timeSpan.Seconds)-28800
So I added a Calculated field, I now get 0 instead of Nothing but it sums for more days + Warning [rsAggregateOfNonNumericData] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Sec_Diff.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.  Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data.

Comment: Your original question has been answered. It might be best to create a new question if you can't find a solution for your new problem.

Comment: maybe you can take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710749/ssrs-format-seconds-as-time-negative-seconds