# SSRS Format seconds as time (negative seconds)

Tags: reporting-services, time, format

I have a column with integers:  TotalSec that has seconds. It can be 0, negative or positive.

I have to format these seconds in a report. But cant get something working for the negative seconds.

My logic: 
For 0 = Nothing, 
For Positive format as HH:mm:ss
For Negative - ABS the value then format as -HH:mm:ss

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)=0, Nothing, IiF(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)>0,
Format(DateAdd("s",SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), "-" & Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")))
```

I get an #Error for the Negative numbers. With the warning:

```
Warning 2   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘TotalSec.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.  Parameter name: value
```

Comment: Can't you make it work without the ABS and the -?

Comment: For negative seconds? I can't. I get the same #Error when I try to apply the =Format(DateAdd("s",SUM(Fields!Sec_Diff.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss") to negative numbers. That if why I wanted to make it ABS and then just add a (-) in front

Answer (score 1):

It worked like this:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)=0,Nothing,IIF(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)< 0,"-"&Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"),Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!TotalSec.Value)), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the previous answer:

```
=IIf(Fields!elapsed.Value < 0, "-", "+")
&
Format(
    DateAdd(
        "s",
        Abs(Fields!elapsed.Value),
        "00:00:00"
    ),
    "HH:mm:ss" ' can be m:ss
)
```

The `"+"` is to keep the results lined up, and can be replaced with `""` if desired.